# HTTP 404 error code in spring MVC web app for hello world app

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement a simple Spring MVC web app.I build a project in eclipse 
And during deployment over tomcat  i am getting this error.

Error Code:
[image]

Folder Structure
[image]
Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <display-name>Theka Desi Khana</display-name>
  <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


</beans>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.theka.desi.Controllers" />



    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->

     <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean> 


    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />    




</beans:beans>
```

HomeController

```
   package com.theka.desi.Controllers;


import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    public ServletContext getServletContext() {
        return servletContext;
    }

    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }



    @RequestMapping("/")
        public String welcome() {
            return "redirect:/home";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/home")
        public ModelAndView home() {
            ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("index");

            return view;
        }






}
```

Console Log:

```
   Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:desi' did not find a matching property.
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.65
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 9 2015 08:36:58 UTC
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.65.0
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\nand\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         G:\Softy\apache-tomcat-7.0.65-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.65
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\nand\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=G:\Softy\apache-tomcat-7.0.65-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.65
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\nand\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=G:\Softy\apache-tomcat-7.0.65-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.65\endorsed
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;.
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1234 ms
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.65
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Mar 26, 2016 6:09:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
Mar 26, 2016 6:10:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 26, 2016 6:10:00 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 26, 2016 6:10:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4357 ms
Mar 26, 2016 6:10:50 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase modified
SEVERE:     Resource '/WEB-INF/classes/com/theka/desi/Controllers/HomeController.class' is missing
Mar 26, 2016 6:10:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/desi] has started
Mar 26, 2016 6:10:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
Mar 26, 2016 6:10:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 26, 2016 6:10:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 26, 2016 6:10:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mar 26, 2016 6:10:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Mar 26, 2016 6:10:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
Mar 26, 2016 6:10:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/desi] is completed
```

Deployment directory structure 
   [image]

I ran project as 
 Prject_> Run As>Run on Server

Comment: any log of catalina.out

Comment: @andy i have added log. There is no log related mapping.

Comment: The log doesn't show that app is deployed.

Comment: I agree with @RomanC. Are you sure that your app is configured to be deployed in the Tomcat server?

Comment: these is no desi in log, maybe you need try to publish you project to tomcat

Comment: when im running it on tomcat server then i am getting this error

Comment: C:\Users\nand\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps check whether there is a folder desi in this folder?

Comment: @andy that folder is empty. What should i do?

Comment: do you start tomcat with run the project on server?

Comment: @andy i did same .getting same error .Here is log :INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\nand\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\desi\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-3.0-alpha-1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Comment: @andy i have added " <scope>provided</scope>" to resolve previous error but still i have same error

Comment: you can update the log then maybe other one can help.

Comment: @andy i have update the log and also added pic of deployment directory. Desi and all other sub folder is created there but error still remain same.How i am running my project ::Project-> Run As>Run on Server

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy by default, if you have only one application deployed to tomcat, the context root will be '/'. Unless you have specifically said that it is `/desi` then you should be using `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: sorry should have said "deployed by eclipse" rather than "deployed in tomcat". If you add it to Tomcat, then unless the directory in tomcat webapp is called "ROOT" it will use the name of the application folder (so if you used `myapp` it would expect `localhost:8080\myapp`

Answer (score 0):

In Spring configuration file you have used

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.theka.desi.Controllers" />
```

is it the package name where the controllers reside? If no, change it to the actual package.

Next, the controller class should have `@Controller` annotation, without it Spring can't use other annotations needed to map the requested URL `http://localhost:8080/desi/`.

Comment: Package file  path is correct and also mentioned @controller in my controller class.I have updated class in question. plz have a look and suggest some solution

Comment: What a Spring version?

Comment: <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>